# getting values from <Field> onSubmit using React.js and redux.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am learning Reactjs, redux, and I want to simply print to console.log the username and password for this form.

I have tried console.log(e.target.user.value) but I a getting no results.

here is the handle function. [image]

and then the Form and 2 fields. [image]

[image]

how can I print the value of username and password in the handleSubmit function ?

Comment: Please include your code in text format instead of images, and preferably also with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code:

```
handleSubmit = values => {
   console.log('values',values);
   //Here you will get values in values.username & values.password
}

render(){
  const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
  return(
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}>
        <div className="form-inputs">
         <Field type="text" label="Name" name="username" data-fieldname="username" 
           component={bootstrapFormField} placeholder="Username" />
         <Field type="password" label="Password" name="password" data- 
           fieldname="password" component={bootstrapFormField} 
           placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-actions text-right">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-submit green">
                Sign In
          </button>
        </div>
    </form>
   )
}
```